# bash parameter expansion not working as expected

Tags: bash

The below example is from one of the many web pages I consulted. I cannot get the "remove from beginning till marker" or "remove from marker till end" to work, perhaps something is wrong with how I specify the pattern? The final goal is to remove everything from a line of text, from a given marker till the end. A solution with sed might well be found too but this one annoys me.

```
VERSION=0.11.3-issue#18.6a0b43d.123
# this one works as expected
echo ${VERSION/\#/}
0.11.3-issue18.6a0b43d.123
# all the others don't, they return the input unchanged
# trying to remove the 'i' to get the syntax straight
echo ${VERSION%i}
0.11.3-issue#18.6a0b43d.123
echo ${VERSION%\i}
0.11.3-issue#18.6a0b43d.123
${VERSION%%\i}
0.11.3-issue#18.6a0b43d.123
echo ${VERSION%%i}
0.11.3-issue#18.6a0b43d.123
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: echo ${VERSION%i}
0.11.3-

Comment: btw thanks for cleaning up my typing. How can I force a line-feed into this editor?

Comment: Then do `echo ${VERSION%i*}`

Comment: Doesn't the ENTER key work?

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Care to explain what I missed? It looks like regex syntax, but 'i' by itself makes a RE too, doesn't it?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100

Comment: OK, I think I got all of it now, thanks chaps. Regarding how to use the editor: yes yes the ENTER works, it works far too hard: as soon as I hit it, my text is sent & published, rather than getting a CR/LF inserted. I tried ctrl-J and ctrl-M, they invoke auxiliary functions of the editor. This is with very recent versions of Firefox and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the thing after # or % isn't a marker, but a pattern.

```
echo ${VERSION%i*}
```

Add asterisks to match the rest of the value.